# How to stop triggered animation in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, 2d-games

I'm actually trying to create a game in which the player is set to idle animation by default, so upon trigger when the hook grabs the jewel the rope wrap animation starts but I cant seem to be able to stop the rope wrap animation and go back to idle. The hook also grab more then one item, can anyone assist me with this? Here's an visual illustration of the animation

[Idle Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rZHf.jpg)

[Rope Wrap - The player starts winching in the jewel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wVTd.jpg)

Here's the code for the Hook Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HookScripts : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField]
private Transform itemHolder;

private bool itemAttached;

private HookMovement hookMovement;

private PlayerAnimation playerAnim;

void Awake() {
    hookMovement = GetComponentInParent<HookMovement>();
    playerAnim = GetComponentInParent<PlayerAnimation>();
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target) {

    if (target.tag == Tags.PINK_GEM || target.tag == Tags.GREEN_GEM || target.tag == Tags.BLUE_GEM 
        || target.tag == Tags.ORANGE_GEM || target.tag == Tags.PURPLE_GEM 
        || target.tag == Tags.LIGHT_BLUE_GEM || target.tag == Tags.PINK_GEM_SMALL 
        || target.tag == Tags.LARGE_STONE || target.tag == Tags.SMALL_STONE){

        itemAttached = true;

        target.transform.parent = itemHolder;
        target.transform.position = itemHolder.position;
        // Set the position of the hook to the position of the item

        hookMovement.move_Speed = target.GetComponent<ItemScripts>().hook_Speed;

        hookMovement.HookAttachedItem();

        //animate player
        playerAnim.PullingItemAnimation();


        if (target.tag == Tags.PINK_GEM || target.tag == Tags.GREEN_GEM || target.tag == Tags.BLUE_GEM
            || target.tag == Tags.ORANGE_GEM || target.tag == Tags.PURPLE_GEM
            || target.tag == Tags.LIGHT_BLUE_GEM || target.tag == Tags.PINK_GEM_SMALL)
        {

            SoundManager.instance.HookGrab_Jewel();
        }
        else if (target.tag == Tags.LARGE_STONE || target.tag == Tags.SMALL_STONE){

            SoundManager.instance.HookGrab_Stone();
        }

            SoundManager.instance.WinchCrank(true);

    } // If the target is an item

    if (target.tag == Tags.DELIVER_ITEM){

        if(itemAttached){

            itemAttached = false;
            Transform objChild = itemHolder.GetChild(0);
            objChild.parent = null;
            objChild.gameObject.SetActive(false);

            playerAnim.IdleAnimation();
            SoundManager.instance.WinchCrank(false);

        }
    }// Remove items after winching

}// On trigger enter
```

}

And here is the code for the Player Animation Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator anim;

    void Awake()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    public void IdleAnimation()
    {
        anim.SetTrigger("Idle");
    }

    public void PullingItemAnimation()
    {
        anim.SetTrigger("ropeWrap");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never been good with animation in Unity, but I can help with the multiple items problem. Currently, when the hook hits an item, all you check is what the item is; the itemAttached variable is set, but never really used. You need to add some check that says, "If I already have an item, don't pick another one up. In practice, that'd simply be adding an and to the item collection conditional:

```
if (!itemAttached && (target.tag == Tags.PINK_GEM || target.tag == Tags.GREEN_GEM || target.tag == Tags.BLUE_GEM 
        || target.tag == Tags.ORANGE_GEM || target.tag == Tags.PURPLE_GEM 
        || target.tag == Tags.LIGHT_BLUE_GEM || target.tag == Tags.PINK_GEM_SMALL 
        || target.tag == Tags.LARGE_STONE || target.tag == Tags.SMALL_STONE)){
    //attach the item
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, definitely solved the hook problem!